# PHP - Escape dollar sign

Tags: php

How can I modify a string to ensure that the dollar sign is preceded by an odd number of backslashes?

```
<?php
  $string = file_get_contents('somefile.txt');
  echo($string."\n");
  $string=str_replace ('$' , '\$' ,$string);
  echo($string."\n");
 ?>
```

somefile.txt

```
$first
\$second
\\$third
\\\$forth
\\\\$fifth
```

OUTPUT

```
    $first
\$second
\\$third
\\\$forth
\\\\$fifth
\$first
\\$second
\\\$third
\\\\$forth
\\\\\$fifth
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. In a single quoted string (`'...'`) you don't have to escape it at all.

Comment: check this out: http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Escape characters only have meaning in the source code. Once the source code has been parsed then they will have been replaced by whatever character the escape sequence represented and you don't have them any more (and you certainly couldn't put them in — it's too late). You might want to generate some source code (in some language or data format) and ensure that the data is escaped properly, but it isn't clear if you are doing that or what language you are trying to generate.

Comment: @arkascha  I wish the dollar sign in the string to have only an odd number of backslashes in front of it.  If even, I am escaping the backslashes.   I agree you don't need to escape with single quotes, but that isn't the issue.

Comment: @Quentin  Maybe I should rewrite the question.  I wish the dollar sign to have an odd number of backslashes in front of it so that if it were source code, it would be escaped.

Comment: If that isn't the issue, then why did you post that example? Note that escaping is nothing absolute! It depends on _where_ you escape. You have to escape different in different situations! In a single quoted string: not at all: in a double quoted string: with a single backslash. Inside a regular expression: depends, ... Don't get this wrong, but it appears that you have not really understood what escaping does and what it is required for. Blindly escaping something where it isn't require _will not work_. It will alter you content in a way you don't want to.

Comment: @arkascha  I didn't realize it at the time, but agree it was a bad example.  Please see my updated post.

Comment: Now your question is even more unclear. Maybe instead of trying to tell how you want to try to escape something... Why don't you simply post your _real_ issue you want to solve? _Keep your question simple!_

Comment: @arkascha.  If I told you my real issue, I will really get marked down!  Rainy day in Seattle.  Painting my daughters room, and waiting for the paint to dry.  Bored, so thought I would come up with a basic template engine just for fun.  It takes user content, parses it, and PHP file which defines a class where one of the methods contains some heardoc.  Don't want the user provided content to have any un-escaped dollar signs.  Just for fun :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do what you are asking.

```
$string = '$first \$second \\$third  \\\$forth \\\\$fifth';
echo $string."\n";
$string = str_replace(['\\','$'], ['', '\$'], $string);
echo $string."\n";
```

In a way, anyway. It removes all `\` first and then it changes ALL `$` to `\$`

BTW, `echo` isn't a function. :)

I'm not a regex wizard, so the following will add a backslash to all zero and even number `\` preceding a `$` (EXCEPT for the first one in the string):

```
$string = <<<'EOL'
$first $another \$second \\$third  \\\$forth \\\\$fifth
EOL;
var_dump($string);
$string = preg_replace('/([^\\\])(([\\\]{2})+)?\$/', '$1$2\\\$', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Thanks keyboardSmasher.  Yes, this is what I am asking.  Think there is a good way to only add a backslash if there is zero or an even number of existing preceding backslashes?  And yep, `echo` is a language constraint I recall.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a regular expression version. You can play around with it to include the first `$` in the string.

Comment: @user1032531 if you are doing a simple template engine, since those tend to do a _lot_ of parsing, just remember: regexes are slow, `str_replace` is fast :) Whenever possible, prefer a simple string replacement when it does what you need. I personally _love_ regexes (I'm no wizard either) but use them sparingly in code that has a *lot* of string processing to do!

Answer (score 19):

You're in single quotes. In single quotes a dollar sign isn't parsed as anything. Nothing is auto parsed in single quotes in php. If you use double quotes they are automatically parsed:

```
echo "$var"; // this will print the value of $var;
echo '$var'; // this will print $var;
echo "\$var";// this escapes the dollar sign so it will print $var;
```

If the string was created in double quotes, you can't just escape the dollar sign afterwards, because it's already been parsed as a variable.
Example:

```
$var = 'hello';
$str = "$var";
```

At this point you'd be trying to add an escape \$ when the value of $str is hello not $var.

Comment: Thanks Robert,  Unfortunately, I did not do a very good job describing what I was trying to accomplish, and it does not answer my question.  +1 for a very informative answer, however.