# Notice: Undefined variable: data table contains '$' symbol on php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have trouble, I can't open the table from my database SQL server, because my table contains the $ symbol so it can't display the table in PHP.

How to convert so that the symbol can be read in PHP so that it can display a table from that table

this is my Connection source

```
$server = "NAV01";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"LIVE", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"1234");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo) or die ( "Connection failed:" );

$sql = "SELECT ID, Quantity, ImposeX, Depth, Width FROM [Poject PT$PV Job Item]";

$query = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql) or die ("Database failed:" );

while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

// xxxxxxxxxxxxx - my data

} ?>
```

Comment: How to convert so that the symbol can be read in php so that it can display a table from that table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Escape dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640682/php-escape-dollar-sign)